# plotly-dash: How to get predefined yaxis range after zoom out?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

When I create a graph in plotly-dash, I define a fix range for the yaxis:

```
...
'layout': go.Layout(title='Graph', xaxis=dict(title="Time"), yaxis=dict(... , range=[0, 100], ...),
...
```

This works fine.

But after a zoomout event (doubleclick in the chart) the yaxis is autoscaled by the given data range. Is there a way to turn the autoscaling on zoomout off? Or exists any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go.Layout and e.g. `go.Scatter` are eventually passed to `go.Figure`.
In dash the go.Figure object is than passed on to `dcc.Graph`.

`dcc.Graph` accepts an config argument which is able to set which buttons to show, logo, how events are handled and much more.

from the doc-string of `dcc.Graph`:

```
- doubleClick (a value equal to: false, 'reset', 'autosize', 'reset+autosize'; optional):   Double click interaction (false, 'reset', 'autosize' or 'reset+autosize')
```

**example**

```
dcc.Graph(
    figure=go.Figure(data, layout),
    config={'doubleClick': 'autosize'}
)
```

**abbreviations**:

```
dcc short for dash_core_components
go short for plotly.graph_objs
```

**references**:

- https://plot.ly/python/configuration-options/
- https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/plot_api/plot_config.js#L6
- https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/blob/c107e0fc5e5c6e7a238e5570ea6a619533121575/dash_core_components/Graph.py#L70

Comment: Hi erkandem. Thanks for your elaborate answer and especially for the links! I already tried the dcc.graph with config = {'doubleClick' : 'reset'}, but it didn't make any difference (autoscaling still happened on zoomout). Instead of 'reset' I checked the False option just to test if my config = '...' definiton has any effect. But this seems to work (after zoom in no reaction on double click).